# How to use a canonical link tag in a static page?

Tags: html, url

What is canonical linking and how can I use it in a static site?

How do we use canonical linking? Suppose we have two pages `page1.html` and `page2.html`, I want to canonical linking for page2. Where should we write the canonical link tags?

Comment: Do page 1 and page 2 have different content?   In other words, do you want two different canonical tags signaling that each page is unique, or do you want to use the same tag indicating one is duplicate of the other?

Comment: Here is Googles page on the subject. It should help. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: If you have an entirely "static site" and the content for each URL is unique then you probably don't _need_ any canonical tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the canonical links within the element `<head>` and you will find this at the top of your HTML document. You will find this information all on Google Webmasters:

> [Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#2)
>
> Suppose you want `https://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome/` to be the preferred URL, even though a variety of URLs can access this content. You can indicate this to search engines as follows:
>
> - Mark up the canonical page and any other variants with a rel="canonical" link element. Add a `<link>` element with the attribute rel="canonical" to the  section of these pages:
>   `<link rel="canonical" href="https://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome" />`
>
> This indicates the preferred URL to use to access the green dress post, so that the search results will be more likely to show users that URL structure. (Note: We attempt to respect this, but cannot guarantee this in all cases.)

*So if you want page 2 to refer to page 1 then you use something like this:*

```
<head>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/page1.html" />
</head>
```

If the content is unique on both pages and related to one another then you will be better of using [PREV and NEXT](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en).